# What is the benefit of using Bitnami deployments over regular ones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I wanted to deploy a CouchDB instance, I saw that there was a Bitnami version and a regular version available. I did some reading about Bitnami but it's still not clear to me what would be the benefit of using their image over the regular one?

Answer (score 1):

Main benefits from using Bitnami deployments are:

- they're always up to date (not always true with others)
- ease of deployment (you don't have to worry about configuration, credentials etc.)
- great [documentation & tutorials](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/) for their deployments

You can also manage all Bitnami deployments from [Bitnami Launchpad](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/get-started-launchpad/) - you just need a free account. Their site uses GCP's Deployment Manager over the API but this simplifies things even more. But that applies only to Bitnami Deployments.

Furthermore there is a [wide selection of different technology stacks](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/) they offer.